# ubuntu : redirecting ssh command to existing xterm

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, remote, linux-terminal

This command execute remotely on "machine name" the command "glxgears" on a new xterm terminal:

```
xterm -hold -e sshpass -p <password> ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user name>@<machine name> glxgears
```

What I would like to do, is to start other remote ssh commands on "machine name" that would run from the same xterm (the one glxgears is already running in).

That seems to be possible, as the following works:

if I type

```
w
```

I see this line:

```
<username>  pts/37   :0               12:41    3:30   0.00s  0.00s sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzz ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user name>@<machine name> glxgears
```

and

```
echo "test" > /dev/pts/37
```

does print "test" in the xterm "glxgear" is running in.

But:

```
xterm -hold -e sshpass -p <passwd> ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<machine name> echo "test" > /dev/pts/37
```

print "test" in a new xterm.

I guess the command 'echo "test" > /dev/pts/37' is run on "machine name" rather than 'echo "test"' being run on "machine name" and redirected to /pts/37 on the client machine.

What would be the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire command to be remotely executed, including the redirection, would need to be quoted to prevent the redirection operator from being consumed by the local shell:

```
ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <username>@<machine name> "echo 'test' > /dev/pts/37"
```

Comment: that works, thx. But I am confused. The remote machine will run "echo 'test' > /dev/pts/37" but /dev/pts/37 exits only on the machine that execute the command via ssh ... obviously I am wrong, since this is working, what am I missing ?